# How to set GridView's Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rows

I have a `GridView` containing Excel sheet Records. And I want to add them to my `DataTable`. I want to access my GridView's second row.This is a piece of my code.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
     string Template = row.Cells[0].Text;
     string Cust_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;
     int Invoice_No = int.Parse(row.Cells[2].Text);
}
```

I tried something like

```
int rowNum = GridView1.Rows[1]
```

but I got this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to 'int'

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: `GridView1.Rows[1]` should work, so what problem did you encounter? Apart from that the question is unclear. You are already showing a different way to access the rows in a GridView, by using a `foreach`-loop. What is the problem with that approach?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I tried this `int rowNum = GridView1.Rows[1]` it throws an error, > Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to 'int'

Comment: @Nuke: 
You should have mentioned this error in your question since it changes it completely. Your approach is correct, you can use use the indexer of `GridViewRowCollection` which is returned by `gridView.Rows`. So via `GridView1.Rows[1]` you get the second row. But if you instead want to get the row-index of a given `GridViewRow` use [Harvey's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30703653/284240) suggestion to use the `RowIndex`-property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rowIndex` property of the `GridViewRow` object that you are using in the loop. You can match the index with your required index and then do the needful. Something like this :

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
     int rowindex= row.rowIndex;
     if(rowindex==yourValue)
     {
       //do your logic.
     }
}
```

Check this link for some info on this : [GridViewRow.RowIndex Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.